# How to disable cell editing in VB.Net data grids?

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagrid

I have a form with a datagrid and a textbox. I load the data as follows and i want following things to be done.

```
Private Sub findItem()
    Dim strSql As String

    strSql = "SELECT it_code,It_name FROM tb_items WHERE it_name Like '%" & Trim(txtItemName.Text) & "%'"

    Dim tempItem As DataTable
    tempItem = myTbClass.myFunctionFetchTbData(strSql)

    dgItem.DataSource = Nothing
    dgItem.AutoGenerateColumns = False

    dgItem.ColumnCount = 2

    dgItem.Columns(0).Name = "IT_NAME"
    dgItem.Columns(0).HeaderText = "IT NAME"
    dgItem.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "it_name"
    dgItem.Columns(0).Width = 350
    dgItem.Columns(0).ReadOnly = True

    dgItem.Columns(1).Name = "IT_CODE"
    dgItem.Columns(1).HeaderText = "IT CODE"
    dgItem.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "it_code"
    dgItem.Columns(1).Width = 300
    dgItem.Columns(1).ReadOnly = True

    dgItem.DataSource = tempItem

End Sub
```

1. I want to disable users typing inside cells. I tried the following but non of them are working. What is the correct method of doing it?

   DataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically
   dataGridView1.Rows(0).ReadOnly = false
   dataGridView1.Columns(0).ReadOnly = false

Comment: A `DataGridView` is a `DataGridView`, not a datagrid. It's not hard to use the actual names of things and it can prevent people wasting time if they make the wrong assumption.

Comment: Don't ask two questions in one question. If you have two issues, create two questions. Then people can answer them independently and you can accept the best answer for each question. I have deleted your second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `DataGridView` control to be read-only then set the `ReadOnly` property of the grid to `True`. It would also likely make sense to set the `AllowUserToAddRows` and `AllowUserToDeleteRows` properties to `False`.